# How to debug PhantomJS when running through Karma

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, remote-debugging, karma-runner

I test through Jasmine, Karma and a variety of browsers. I'm currently debugging a test that fails only in PhantomJS.

I'd like to debug this call, so I've setup a custom PhantomJS launcher in karma that runs it with the debug port open.

I'm able to access the remote debugger in Chrome through that port, however, it seems to know nothing about any of my test files. It reports an "about:blank" and a "localhost:9876" (the karma server that Phantom is hitting) but when I try to debug that location, it shows none of the source files or Jasmine spec files.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? I've read the PhantomJS docs on the remote debugging feature and they don't shed any light on this issue, AFAIK.

Comment: For those who want to disable certain test just for PhantomJS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39864643/3959662

Answer (score 10):

I struggled mightily with this, it was not straightforward.

I ended up [proposing a change to karma-phantomjs-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/pull/43). It was merged and is now in the latest versions.

Comment: It's merged already! Would be good to update the answer with https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher

Comment: OK I've updated the answer to reflect current reality.