# How to debug an error on PhantomJS with karma + webpack?

Tags: webpack, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm running karma using Chrome and PhantomJS as browsers. With Chrome, I get no errors; with PhantomJS I get this:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'action(dstObject[propName], srcObject[propName])')
  at webpack:///~/my-library/dist/my-library.full.js:94:0 <- index.js:10919

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

Basically, my tests are not running because of something going on with `my-library`, which is a node dependency. My question is this: **how can I debug this error?**

I'm calling karma with `karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js` and there I can see that the `files:['./index.js']`, when I look in this file I see this:

```
// require all test files (files that ends with .spec.js)
const testsContext = require.context('./specs', true, /\.spec$/)
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext)
```

`require.context` is a webpack function which creates a context loading my spec files, which are returned by `testsContext.keys()` but this is as far as I've been able to go.

I would appreciate any ideas to understand what is actually going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923635/how-to-debug-phantomjs-when-running-through-karma?rq=1